# CSS FONT in ASP.NET

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I am facing a big problem in my ASP.NEt MVC4 application CSS
For loading a new font i am using
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

```
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'RobotoBoldItalic';
  src: url("../../../Content/KarmaLoopMobileContent/font/Roboto-BoldItalic-webfont.eot");
  src: url("../../../Content/KarmaLoopMobileContent/font/Roboto-BoldItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../../../Content/KarmaLoopMobileContent/font/Roboto-BoldItalic-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("../../../Content/KarmaLoopMobileContent/font/Roboto-BoldItalic-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../../../Content/KarmaLoopMobileContent/font/Roboto-BoldItalic-webfont.svg#RobotoBoldItalic") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

But the font does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Look in firebug/dev tools and see if there are any errors on page load.